# Philips Hue: how to create group for user

Tags: philips-hue

I try to use Philips Hue API to create groups for each user. The document here: [Philips Hue API](http://developers.meethue.com/2_groupsapi.html#22_create_group) As in this document states:

```
2.2.    Create group
This method is not supported in the 1.0 version of the API. It is scheduled for release in the next version of the API.
```

This point makes me feel confusing. If currently API doesn't support create group, how other operations (such as view group, change attributes ...) can happen. Do I misunderstand something ?

Moreover, if we create a group, does this group share over all users, or for only one user that create this group. ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is not up to date; the API version is currently at version 1.3.0.
You can create groups if your Hue bridge is connected to the internet and you have updated it.

To do so, send this **POST** command to **/api/*username*/groups/** where ***username*** is the username you have created to access the API.

```
{
    "name":"Test",
    "lights": ["1","2"]
}
```

*lights* is the array of lights you wish to associate this group with.

*name* is the friendly name for this group.

#### To change a group's name or lights associated with it:

send **PUT** commands to **/api/username/groups/*id*/**

*id* is the ID of your newly created group

#### To delete a group:

send an empty **DELETE** command to **/api/*username*/groups/*id*/**

Because this portion of the API is undocumented, it may be subject to change or removal, or may present instability in your Hue system. Use the group API at your own risk.

send commands to groups the same way you would send them to an individual light (change colors, turn on/off, etc.)

Group 0 controls ALL lights.

Groups are accessible by all users.

Comment: They updated the documentation, 'groups' is now described properly: [developers.meethue.com](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/groups-api)

Comment: I see that! Apparently the developer documentation has been updated within the last two weeks. As of the writing of my answer, dev documentation was open to the public-- but now requires registration in order to view.